# Button ControlTemplate and rounded corners

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a controltemplate for buttons. I want to make the buttons with rounded corners. How should I do this?

I tried CornerRadius for button in the Border but it doesn't work. The background of the button has set to an image that has corner borders and the button looks akward as I can't set the corners for the button.

Comment: Post your ControlTemplate mark-up.

Comment: Posted my ControlTemplate above, CornerRadius has no effect.

Answer (score 9):

Try the following:

```
<Style x:Key="GlassButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="42" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="border"
                        CornerRadius="25"
                        BorderThickness="4"
                        Background="#AA000000"
                        BorderBrush="Red"
                        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ButtonContentPresenter"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF4788c8" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF4788c8" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD190" Offset="0.35" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="0.95" />
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFD190" Offset="1" />
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="content" Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TranslateTransform Y="1.0" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF282828" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF282828" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Opacity" Value="0.7" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Gosh, in ios storyboard - its just a dynamic property. "layer.cornerRadius". After  seeing this, I give up creating rounded corners in windows apps. :D

Comment: @Dhana it's also just one property. But the Button is composed of a Border-Object and a Content Presenter, so you have to edit the Button Template because you only have to change the Corner Radius of the border element.