# wpf how to create a custom button

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, button, controltemplate

In WPF how do I make a button with a white border with a 5 pixel radius, a dark gray background and white text? It would be nice if it still had all the mouse over and ispressed effect too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to understand how [Control Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.aspx) work in WPF. [This sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on applying Control Templates on button by `MSDN` should get you started.

There's is also a [similar SO QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594065/button-controltemplate-and-rounded-corners) that should help you.